# Sollte 112 als hundertzwölf, hundertundzwölf, einhundertzwölf oder einhundertundzwölf geschrieben werden?

Tags: numbers

Ich kenne die Regel, dass man die Zahlen von 1 - 12 ausschreiben soll und dann nur noch als Zahlen mit Ziffern schreiben soll.

Jedoch gibt es die ausgeschriebene Variante jeder Zahl. Ich würde gerne wissen, wie es bei Zahlen zwischen 101 und 199 aussieht. Welche der folgenden Varianten ist richtig bzw. akzeptabel (bitte mit Quelle)?

- Hundertzwölf
- Hundertundzwölf
- Einhundertzwölf
- Einhundertundzwölf

Comment: Als Telefonnummer wäre es eins-eins-zwei bzw. eins-eins-zwo.

Comment: Und ansonsten versteht jeder Deutsche alle vier Varianten. Ugs. hundertzwölf, jede überflüssige Silbe wird weggelassen.

Comment: Als Jahreszahl (mündlich) sogar _eins-zwölf_, wie _zwanzig-zwölf_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laut dem [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hundert) sind alle von Dir genannten Schreibweisen korrekt.

Ich würde aber vom Bauchgefühl bei besonders förmlichen Angaben das "ein" sowie das "und" in die geschriebene Zahl einfügen. "Einhundertundzwölf" klingt sauberer als "Hundertzwölf".

---

*Zur Vollständigkeit dieser Antwort sei darauf hingewiesen, dass das Weglassen der Zahl natürlich nur bei "1" am Anfang geht. Also [Ein]hundert, [Ein]tausend.*

Comment: Ich stimme deinem Bauchgefühl zu und gebe auch einen Grund an: Zahlen ausschreiben ist vor allem dann nötig, wenn es darum geht Missverständnisse zu vermeiden, etwa auf Checks oder Kaufverträgen. Hier sollte außerdem vermieden werden, dass ein Betrag nachträglich verändert werden kann. Aus "Hundertundzwölf" kann man "Neunhundertundzwölf" machen. Aus "Einhundertundzwölf" ist das nicht möglich. Natürlich lässt sich daraus immernoch "Zehntausendeinhundertundzwölf" machen, aber zumindest sind die manipulationsmöglichkeiten verringert.

Answer (score 6):

In *Duden ‒ Die deutsche Rechtschreibung*, 25. Aufl. Mannheim 2009 werden alle vier Varianten gleichwertig nebeneinander genannt:

> hunderteins, hundertundeins, einhunderteins, einhundertundeins

In *Duden – Richtiges und gutes Deutsch*, 6. Aufl. Mannheim 2007 wird hierzu erwähnt:

> Soweit es nicht auf besondere Genauigkeit ankommt, lässt man bei der Wiedergabe der Zahlen von 100 bis 199 *ein-* gewöhnlich weg: *183 = hundertdreiundachtzig* oder *einhundertdreiundachtzig.* Steht aber eine größere Einheit davor, muss *ein-* mitgesprochen und auch mitgeschrieben werden: *2 183 = zweitausendeinhundertdreiundachtzig.*

Answer (score 3):

Ich habe zwar bis jetzt schon alle Varianten angetroffen, doch ist "Einhundertzwölf" am gebräuchlichsten (Google-Suchangaben für "Einhundertzwölf" ca. 680k, bei den Restlichen unter 10k) und "Hundertundzwölf" wird, wenn überhaupt, mehr für Bibelangaben genutzt, die restlichen Varianten sind, in meiner Erfahrung, mehr "Szenewörter".

Auch bei anderen Zahlen über 100 wird dieselbe Technik angewandt (Einhunderteins, Einhundertzwei, Einhundertdrei, etc., etc.).