# Kann man die Zahl 100 (bzw. 1.000, 1.000.000) nur als "hundert" lesen?

Tags: usage, pronunciation, numbers

> Es sind 100 Schüler in meinem Gymnasium, die dieses Jahr einen Abschluss machen werden.

Wie liest man diesen Satz?

> (a) Es sind **hundert** Schüler in meinem Gymnasium, …
>
> (b) Es sind **ein hundert** Schüler in meinem Gymnasium, …

Ich glaube, (b) ist die formelle Version, aber ist es auch korrekt, (a) zu lesen?

(Dieselbe Frage für die Zahlen 1.000, 1.000.000 usw.)

Comment: Related: [Sollte 112 als hundertzwölf, hundertundzwölf, einhundertzwölf oder einhundertundzwölf geschrieben werden?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15957/sollte-112-als-hundertzw%C3%B6lf-hundertundzw%C3%B6lf-einhundertzw%C3%B6lf-oder-einhundertund)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Einhundert* und *eintausend* können immer als *hundert* bzw. *tausend* ausgesprochen werden, in der gesprochenen Sprache werden auch meist die Kurzformen verwendet, außer, man möchte die Zahl besonders betonen. Ab 1.000.000 funktioniert das nicht mehr, hier gibt es nur *eine Million*, *eine Milliarde* etc.