# 101.000.000 in Worten

Tags: numbers

Jetzt bin ich etwas verwirrt. Aber ihr könnt mir bestimmt weiterhelfen.

Wie soll man die Zahl 101.000.000 in Worten schreiben:

*Einhunderteine Million* oder *einhunderteins Millionen*?

Comment: Ich würde 'hundert und eine Million' sagen.

Comment: @knut ich bin jetzt noch mehr verwirrt :(

Comment: 'hunderteine Million' ginge auch :)  Siehe auch http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18694/kann-man-die-zahl-100-bzw-1-000-1-000-000-nur-als-hundert-lesen und http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15957/sollte-112-als-hundertzwölf-hundertundzwölf-einhundertzwölf-oder-einhundertund?rq=1

Comment: Hängt davon ab, was damit gemeint ist und entsprechend ob oder was danach steht.

Comment: http://zahlen-ausschreiben.de/ - Für jede Frage des Lebens gibt es ein Webformular

Comment: ausserdem hat MS Word eine Feldfunktion für das Ausschreiben von Zahlen: `\*cardtext` - die funktioniert nur leider nicht bei so großen Zahlen. Hätte mich interessiert, was MS dazu sagt...

Comment: Beide angebotenen Möglichkeiten sind falsch. Richtig ist: *Einhundertein Millionen*

Comment: Es gab eine Antwort, die "einhundertundeine Millionen" vorschlug, zwei Downvotes erhielt und anschließend gelöscht wurde. Meines Empfinden ist das aber die einzig richtige Antwort. Die Einzahl "Million" ist falsch, weil — trotz der Eins — eine Mehrzahl vorliegt. "Einhunderteins" ist falsch, weil — wie in der gelöschten Antwort erwähnt — man ja auch nicht "Eins Zitrone" sagt.

Comment: @tofro woher weiß ich, dass zahlen-ausschreiben.de korrekte Ergebnisse liefert?

Comment: @Em1 Ich habe bis jetzt die Diskussion nur mitverfolgt und keine Antwort downvoted. Ich bin auch der Meinung, dass man Downvote kommentieren sollte, wenn man das tut. Aber allegemein wenn ich ehrlich bin, haben alle Antworten eher mehr Verwirrung gestiftet :) Ich weiß immer noch nicht, wie es nun richtig ist. Vielleicht schreibe ich die Leute von Duden an

Comment: @Mur: wie du sehen kannst,  besteht hier anscheinend kein Konsens, und ich vermute, dass das regional unterschiedlich gehandhabt wird. In der Praxis werden so große Zahlen wahrscheinlich zu selten ausgesprochen und -geschrieben, als das sich eine einheitliche Form gebildet hätte.

Comment: Ich denke, @Gerhard bringt's (fast) auf den Punkt. Es ist eine regionale unterschiedliche Handhabung. Warum nur fast? Nun, ich glaube nicht mal, dass es wirklich regional ist, sondern, wie in meiner Antwort angeführt, eher eine persönliche Auffassung, was nun richtig ist. Das ist schon äußerst regional. :D

Comment: @Em1: ich war versucht, "individuell" zu schreiben - aber ich habe den Eindruck, dass das trotz allem vom Umfeld abhängt (e.g. Familie, Berufszweig, etc). Aber ja, "regional" ist vielleicht ein Wenig zu großräumig :)

Answer (score 3):

Es gab hier mal eine Frage, ob [»Eine halbe Million Häuser wurde zerstört.«](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/24766/1224) korrekt ist oder ob das Verb Plural ist. Dort habe ich in einer Antwort eine Quelle zitiert, die besagt, dass es eine persönliche Auffassung ist, ob hier Plural oder Singular angewandt wird. Es ist zwischen der grammatischen und semantischen Kongruenz zu unterscheiden.
Auf deine Frage bezogen bedeutet das, dass es zum Einen grammatisch *Million* ist, weil ja von *Ein(s)* gesprochen wird, zum Anderen jedoch semantisch *Millionen* ist, weil es ja sehr viel (oder genauer: größer als *Eins*) ist.

Daher ist sowohl *Million* als auch *Millionen* richtig.

Nun zur Frage *Einhundert und Eins* oder *Einhundertundeine*: Nun die Zahl muss schlichtweg flektiert werden. Daher sagt man ja auch nicht *Eins Hundert* oder *Eins Tausend* oder *Eins Million(en)*, sondern *Einhundert", *Eintausend* und *eine Million(en)*.

Endresultat:

> 101.000.000: Einhundertundeine Million(en)
>   101.000.001: Einhundertundeine Million(en) und Eins
>   101.000.001 Dalmatiner: Einhundertundeine Million(en) und ein Dalmatiner

Comment: Ich glaube, Du liegst falsch damit, dass der "ein"-Teil flektiert werden muss. Bei Benutzung mit Plural scheint er unflektiert zu bleiben, vergleiche das Ende von Punkt drei hier: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hundert

Answer (score 2):

Ich würde „einhunderteine Million“ sagen. Eine Regel kann ich dafür leider nicht nennen, aber ein [Beispiel](http://www.bgbl.de/xaver/bgbl/start.xav?startbk=Bundesanzeiger_BGBl&jumpTo=bgbl276s1247.pdf):

> [...] Darlehen bis zu insgesamt 101 400 000,— DM (einhundert eine Million vierhunderttausend Deutsche Mark) aufzunehmen.

Da der Text aus dem Jahr 1976 ist, nehme ich an, dass sich die Zusammenschreibung inzwischen geändert hat.

Answer (score 1):

*Einhunderteins Millionen*. Es sind ja mehrere.

Comment: Mir kommt Million in Einzahl hier auch falsch vor.

Comment: Mehrere: ja! Eins: Nein! Was ist richtig?: »Ich besitze einhunderteins Hemden« oder »Ich besitze einhundertein Hemden«? »Einhunderteins Hühner legen Eier« oder »Einhundertein Hühner legen Eier«? Richtig wäre: »Einhundertein Millionen«: »Der Tunnel hat einhundertein Millionen Euro gekostet.«

Answer (score 1):

Mindestens zwei Möglichkeiten sind mMn "richtig":

> Einhundertundeins Millionen
>
> Einhundert und eine Million

und ich würde die erste Variante wählen. Die zweite halte ich für leicht umgangssprachlich.

Comment: Ich halte auch beide Varianten für richtig, finde aber nichts Umgangssprachliches an der zweiten. In der Tat hört sie sich für mich gehobener an. Gibt es nicht auch Erzählungen aus Tausend und einer Nacht?

Comment: @CarstenS - Versuch's mal mit "Einhundert und eine Birne" - Schlussendlich sind es viele, und das erfordert, um grammatikalisch ganz richtig zu sein, den Plural. Bei Maßeinheiten ("100 Pfund") ist der Singular erlaubt - "Million" ist aber keine Masseinheit.

Comment: ich habe kein Problem mit „einhundert und eine Birne“. Ich sehe nicht ein, warum a priori der grammatische Numerus dem natürlichen folgen muss. Beim Genus erwarten wir das ja auch nicht. Und es sind nun einmal 100 und dann noch eine (Singular).

Comment: @CarstenS In dem Fall ist mMn "Einhundert und eine Million" aber eine Rechenaufgabe - und keine Zahl.

Comment: Sprache ist nicht immer so, wie wir sie aus logischen Gründen gerne hätten.

Comment: Inzwischen denke ich, dass es in der Pluralvariante „einhundertundein“ heißen sollte.

Answer (score 0):

Zunächst die *Million*. Sie ist von der Verwendung her ein Substantiv, wird also groß geschrieben und in der Mehrzahl flektiert. Egal, was davorsteht, es muss *Millionen* heißen, weil es mehr als eine ist.

Nun zu dem Teil davor. Hier gibt es mehrere möglichkeiten. Die führende *ein* kann weggelassen werden – und wird das in der Regel auch. Neben *einhunderteins* und *einhunderteine* bieten sich also auch noch *hundert(und)eins* und *hundert(und)eine* an. Persönlich würde ich dazu tendieren, *die* Million zum Maßstab zu nehmen, und die feminine Form zu verwenden:

> hundertundeine Millionen.

Ich hätte aber auch nichts dagegen, auf die explizite *eins* auszuweichen:

> hundertundeins Millionen.

Answer (score 0):

### einhundertein Millionen

Das Wort »Million« wird grammatisch auf dieselbe Weise wie eine Maßeinheit verwendet (in einem gewissen Sinn trifft das sogar zu).

> Im Tank befinden sich **einhundertein Liter** Benzin.
>   Auf dem Konto liegen **einhundertein Millionen** türkische Lira.
>
> Hier lagern **einhundertein Festmeter** Brennholz.
>   Hier lagern **einhundertein Millionen** Büroklammern.

Noch besserer Vergleich:

Du kannst »Millionen« auch durch »Dutzend« ersetzen; diese beiden Wörter werden ganz genau gleich verwendet (lediglich das Geschlecht ist ein anderes, was im Fall der Mehrzahl aber keinen Unterschied macht)

> In dieser Region wurden **einhundertein Dutzend** Autos zugelassen.
>   In dieser Region wurden **einhundertein Millionen** Autos zugelassen.
>
> Mit viel Geduld kann man diese Torte in **einhundertein Dutzend** Stücke zerschneiden.
>   Mit viel Geduld kann man diese Torte in **einhundertein Millionen** Stücke zerschneiden.

Comment: Noch schöner wären Maßeinheiten, die im Singular und Plural unterschiedliche Formen haben. Hundertein Gläser Wein, hundertein Stämme Holz …

Comment: @CarstenS: Ja, das stimmt, denn von *einer* Million war in der Frage auch nie die Rede. Es wurde nach *einhundertein* Millionen gefragt, und das sind mehr als eine. Daher ist der Plural angebracht, womit man das Geschlecht völlig ignorieren darf. Denn dir wird sicher schon aufgefallen sein, das es im Deutschen im Plural keinen Unterschied zwischen den grammatischen Geschlechtern gibt.

Comment: @CarstenS: Doch, das ist mir ebenso wie dem Fragesteller aufgefallen. Aber: *Der Bauer hat *einhundertein* Kühe und eine Sau, *einhundertein* Stiere und einen Eber und *einhunderein* Kälber und ein Ferkel. Das Geschlecht mach nur im Singular einen Unterschied. Der Plural ist **IMMER** unabhängig vom Geschlecht, auch bei Zahlwörtern, die auf -eins enden.

Comment: @CarstenS: Es sind aber einhundertein Liter (als mehrere Liter, ergo Plural). Immerhin steht auch das Prädikat im Plural (*befinde**n** sich* und nicht *befinde**t** sich*), und da Benzin ein Singularetantum ist, können nur die vielen Liter den Plural des Prädikats erzwungen haben

Comment: @CarstenS: Kannst du das auch irgendwie mit Regeln begründen, oder ist das nur dein Bauchgefühl?

Comment: @CarstenS: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/30310/1487

Comment: @CarstenS: Schön, dass du wiederholst was deiner Meinung nach nicht hilfreich ist. Was wäre denn hilfreich? Ich glaube die von mir gestellte Frage german.stackexchange.com/q/30310/1487 bietet dir nicht nur Gelegenheit, deinen Standpunkt darzulegen, sondern auch Beispiele anzuführen, die du als hilfreicher als meine erachtest.

Comment: Einhundertundein Millionen klingt falsch. Einhundertundein**e** Millionen klingt richtig. Wenn wir uns einig sind, dass Millionen zwar der Plural von Million ist, aber "ein(s), ein, eine" doch Einzahl ist, so kann eigentlich "Millionen" und "ein(s), ein, eine" gar nicht zusammen verwendet werden. Da wir uns gewiss einig sind, dass man es aber doch so macht (ist halt so), müssen wir trotzdem wieder das korrekte Singular Geschlecht anwenden, welches weiblich ist. Also "einhundertundein**e** Millionen". — Das ist zwar keine fundierte Beweisführung, aber naheliegende Herleitung.

Comment: @Em1: Du hast vollkommen recht, wenn du sagst »*"ein(s), ein, eine" ist Einzahl*« und auch wenn du sagst: »*"Millionen" und "ein(s), ein, eine" kann nicht zusammen verwendet werden*«. Aber du scheinst völlig zu übersehen, dass genau das eben **nicht** der Fall ist. Es geht nicht um **1** Million, sondern um **101** Millionen. Also um **mehrere**. Daher **Plural**. Und das Zahlwort lautet ausgeschrieben eben »einhundertein«. Also: **einhundertein Millionen**.

Comment: Nachdem wir inzwischen weiter sind: Ich denke, was Du hier vorschlägst ist eine akzeptable Variante zu "einhunderteine Million". Deine Beispiele sind etwas unglücklich gewählt, da "Liter" sowohl Singular als auch Plural sein kann und "Dutzend" Singular ist. Kühe hätten in der Tat ein besseres Beispiel abgegeben.

Answer (score -2):

Eine einfach Ableitung sollte helfen

21 Ein und Zwanzig

101 Einhundert und Eins

1.001 Eintausend und Eins

101.000 Einhundert und ein Tausend

101.001 Einhundert und ein Tausend und Eins

1.000.001 Einmillionen und Eins

**101.000.000 Einhundert und eine Millionen**

101.000.001 Einhundert und eine Millionen und Eins

Siehe auch: [Wikipedia Zahlennamen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zahlennamen)

Comment: Ja, die Zahl "101" ist "Einhundert und Eins". Aber "101 Dalmatiner" ist "[Einhundertundein Dalmatiner](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hundertundein_Dalmatiner)".