# Kann es vorkommen, dass die Deklination des Plurals vom Geschlecht abhängt?

Tags: declension, grammatical-number, numbers

Wer Deklinationstabellen kennt, weis, dass sie im Fall der deutschen Sprache vier Spalten haben, nämlich:

- Männlich
- Weiblich
- Sächlich
- Mehrzahl

Daraus (und aus meiner rund fünfzigjährigen Erfahrung mit der deutschen Sprache als Muttersprachler) schließe ich, dass im Deutschen alle Deklination von Begriffen, die im Plural stehen, unabhängig vom grammatischen Geschlecht sind.

Ein Beispiel:

> Heute träumte ich von **grünen** Männern, **grünen** Frauen und **grünen** Kindern.

Das Adjektiv »grün« wird hier dreimal genau gleich gebeugt, obwohl die drei Nomen drei verschiedenen Geschlechtern angehören. Was für gewöhnliche Adjektive gilt, gilt auch für Zahlwörter:

> Heute träumte ich von **sieben** Männern, **sieben** Frauen und **sieben** Kindern.

Ich war bisher der Meinung, das gelte uneingeschränkt, immer und ohne jede Ausnahme.

In einer Diskussion, die auf [eine hier gegebene Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/30285/1487) folgte, wurde aber das Gegenteil behauptet.

Es wurde behauptet, dass Zahlwörter, die auf *ein* oder *eins* enden (aber nicht *ein* oder *eins* sind, also nicht ein einzelnes Ding, sondern mehrere Dinge bezeichnen) zumindest dann anders gebildet werden, wenn sie sich auf ein weibliches Nomen beziehen.

Beispiel:

> 1. Einhundertein sächliche Kälber stehen auf der Wiese.
> 2. Einhundertein männliche Stiere stehen auf der Wiese.
> 3. Einhundertein weibliche Kühe stehen auf der Wiese.

Angeblich soll das dritte Beispiel (Einhundertein Kühe) grammatisch falsch sein, weil die Kühe weiblich sind.

Ist das so? Wenn ja: Wie ist der dritte Satz zu korrigieren, und womit ist die Korrektur zu begründen?

Comment: Interessante Frage. Eine Möglichkeit wäre sicherlich, "einhundertundeine Kuh" zu sagen und damit einem [bekannten literarischen Beispiel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tausendundeine_Nacht) zu folgen.

Comment: @Emil: Ich habe das von dir genannte Beispiel schon von Kindheit an für grammatisch falsch gehalten, das nur durch ständige Wiederholung zu einem Gewöhnungseffekt führt, ähnlich wie »Marmor, Stein und Eisen *bricht*« obwohl es korrekt »brechen« heißen müsste. Die Geschichtensammlung umspannt einen Zeitraum von **eintausendein Nächten**, oder dauerte **eintausendein Nächte** lang, und genau so müsste auch der Titel lauten, wenn er grammatisch korrekt sein wollte.

Comment: Einhundertundeins - Ist eine Zahl. Einhundertundeine ist m.A. nach keine Zahl, sondern eine Rechenaufgabe... Analog zu *einundzwanzig Kühe* vs. *zwanzig und eine Kuh*

Comment: Deine Frage geht am Problem vorbei. Die wirkliche Frage ist, ob die Substantive im Singular oder Plural stehen müssen.

Comment: Ich kann die Prämisse schon nicht nachvollziehen: Wahrig hat je Deklination in den Zeilen vier Fälle und Singular/Plural-Spalten. Zudem gibt es bei der starken adjektivischen Deklination unterschiedliche Pluralformen, z. B. Nom: Abgeordnete, Gen: Abgeordneter, Dat: Abgeordneten, Akk: Abgeordnete.

Comment: Nicht wirklich ernst gemeinte Antwort: *der Schild, die Schilde – das Schild, die Schilder.*

Comment: Mein Eindruck ist, dass Du wissen willst, ob es vorkommt, nicht ob es vorkommen kann. Alle Regeln sind doch Abbildungen empirischer Tatsachen. Wenn etwas vorkommt, dann kann es offenbar vorkommen. Aber dass etwas vorkommen kann, ohne dass es das auch tut, ist in der Sprache eine sinnlose Frage.

Comment: Könntest Du bitte klarstellen, ob Du wissen möchtest, was in der Überschrift steht, oder ob Dich auch interessiert, ob die Form von 101 vom Geschlecht abhängen kann (weil es nämlich mit dem Singular gebraucht werden kann)?

Comment: @CarstenS: Mir geht es in dieser Frage schon ausdrücklich um den Plural: »Kann es vorkommen, dass die Deklination des Plurals vom Geschlecht abhängt?« Ich habe das 101-Beispiel nur gewählt, weil es in einer anderen Frage (in der es explizit um dieses Zahlwort geht) als Beispiel für eine angebliche Beeinflussung des Plurals durch das Geschlecht genannt wurde. Mir fällt leider kein anderes Beispiel ein, weil ich dieses Konzept (Geschlecht beeinflusst Beugung des Plurals) grundsätzlich für falsch halte. Ich halte ja auch das 101-Beispiel für falsch.

Comment: @CarstenS: Die von dir wieder gelöschte Antwort ging übrigens auch deswegen an der Frage vorbei, weil du versuchst, den Plural durch einen Singular zu ersetzen. »Einhunderteine weibliche Kuh steht auf der Wiese.« halte ich für falsch, weil hier unzweifelhaft **mehrere** Tiere auf der Wiese steh**en**.

Comment: Der Fragesteller ist offenbar verwirrt und weiß nicht, was seine Frage ist. Mal interessiert ihn die 101, dann doch wieder nicht.

Comment: @CarstenS: Faszinierend, was du über den Fragesteller zu wissen glaubst. Vielleicht fragst du ihn mal? Ach ja, das hast du ja schon gemacht. Hast du auch meine Antwort gelesen? Habe ich geschrieben, dass ich ausdrücklich am Plural interessiert bin? Und dass ich das 101-Beispiel nur gewählt habe, weil mir beim besten Willen kein anderes Beispiel einfällt? Ich bin mit dir einer Meinung, dass einer von uns beiden verwirrt ist. Da ich finde, eine klare Frage gestellt zu haben, und weil ich auch all deine Nachfragen ausführlich beantwortet habe, glaube ich, dass nicht ich der Verwirrte bin.

Comment: Eben weil ich gefragt hatte, war ich überrascht, dass Du die Antwort mit „Kuh“ akzeptiert hast. Wobei die Antwort ansonsten gut war.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Angeblich soll das dritte Beispiel (Einhundertein Kühe) grammatisch falsch sein, weil die Kühe weiblich sind. Ist das so?

Wie man auf [canoonet](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Zahlen/Kardinal.html#Anchor-hundert-44867) nachlesen kann, ist der Satz richtig. Das Beispiel dort:

> zweihundertein Gartenpflanzen

Dein Kommentar:

> »Einhunderteine weibliche Kuh steht auf der Wiese.« halte ich für falsch, weil hier unzweifelhaft mehrere Tiere auf der Wiese stehen.

ist zwar nachvollziehbar, aber "Einhundertundeine Kuh" ist zweifelsfrei richtig. Dies kannst du auf derselben Seite von canoonet nachlesen. Das Beispiel:

> zweihundert(und)eine Gartenpflanze

In der anderen, von dir verlinkten Frage wird's aber noch mal komplizierter, weil das Zahlwort "Million" im Plural verwendet werden kann, auch wenn der semantische Bezug der Einzahl entspricht und entsprechend flektiert wurde. Daher ist "Einhundertundeine Millionen" zwar grammatisch augenscheinlich falsch und dennoch in der realen Welt durchaus richtig.

Comment: Aber er interessiert sich doch nicht für "einhundertein"! (Ich denke übrigens inzwischen, dass es "stehen" heißen sollte.)

Answer (score 0):

Nein, das kommt nicht vor, da hast Du recht.

Comment: Wer meint, dass hier Downvotes oder ähnliches angebracht sind, überlege bitte, ob diese nicht eher der Frage gelten.

Comment: Ich meine, dass für diese Antwort ein Downvote angebracht ist, weil du nur versuchst, der Frage nach dem Mund zu reden. (Die Frage hat übrigens meines Erachtens einen Upvote verdient, da sie auf ein interessantes Phänomen hinweist.)

Comment: @Jan, da mag ein interessantes Phänomen sein, aber das hat mit der Wahl von Singular oder Plural zu tun, und der OP will explizit nichts zum Singular wissen. Der Plural ist einfach.